# R Shiny - Using Selectinput as column selection to subset data frame

Tags: r, shiny, subset

I am using Shiny that takes in a user's txt file. The files composition is completely up to the user - there are no set headers for the file.

```
data_vals <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file1
    if (is.null(file1))return(NULL)
    read.table(fill=TRUE,file=input$file1$datapath, header=TRUE, colClasses = 
    "factor")})
```

From this file, I create a drop down list from the header file that the user submitted:

```
observe({
  req(input$file1)
  dsnames <- names(data_labels())
  cb_options <- list()
  cb_options[dsnames] <- dsnames
  output$choose_filt1<- renderUI({
   selectInput("filt1", "Filter Level 1", cb_options)
  })
 })
```

Then, checkboxes of the unique items in the list are shown for the user to de-select.

```
 observe({
  filt1_data <- data_labels()[,input$filt1]
  filt1_uni <- unique(filt1_data)
  output$inCheckboxGroup1 <- renderUI({
   checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup1", "Filter Level 1 Options:",
                      choices=filt1_uni,
                      selected=filt1_uni)
  })
 })
```

I would like to use some type of subsetting to filter data_vals by the column (namely input$filt1) and by the boxes checked (input$inCheckboxGroup1). I am unsure how to do this, as subset(data_vals, NAME %in% input$inCheckboxGroup1) is looking for the NAME as the column header, rather than looking as the input selected by the user.

I have attempted to use:

```
subset(data_vals, input$inCheckboxGroup1 %in$ input$inCheckboxGroup1)
```

However, this does not produce a table (it's blank). I have also used: `subset(data_vals, Column1Header %in% input$inCheckboxGroup1)`, which works, so I know it's not the checkbox part of the code.

Is it possible to use subsetting in the way I'm describing, or is there another tool to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve your issue by not using `subset`, since your column name is a variable. See the example below:

```
A = 1
B ='am'

# This does not work
mtcars2 = subset(mtcars, B %in% A)

# This works
mtcars2 = mtcars[mtcars[,B] %in% A,]
```

So in your case you could use:

```
data_vals = data_vals[data_vals[,input$filt1] %in% input$checkboxGroup1,]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: THAT WORKED PERFECTLY. This has seriously been killing me for weeks. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Would you consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it sovler your issue? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just did! Thanks again!